# Problema con documentacion de una API (javascript)

Tags: javascript, api

Estuve buscando una api que tenga informacion de paises (ciudades, capitales, monedas, etc) y encontre esta que me parecio super completa https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json el problema es que cuando leo el archivo me dice pagina 1 de 6 y no encuentro la vuelta para pasar de pagina, alguien sabe si tienen alguna forma predeterminada? la documentación de la api no lo dice.

Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use el parametro `page`: por ejemplo `https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json&page=2`

Comment: Siii un exito! gracias genio

Comment: La documentación sí lo comenta: https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/898581-api-basic-call-structures